# Change class of a element when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html

To be more specific, i have an div which has an icon in it. I want it to be so when you click on the div the class in a nav changes but i'm new to javascript so i dont know how to set the javascript to however it might work. And internet got me too confused and all of the answers were for changing the class in the same div/element.

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="nav-container">
            <nav id="navdrop" class="top-bar">

!-- Code in between --!

    <div id="mobileNav" class="mobile-toggle">
      <i class="icon icon_menu"></i>
    </div>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('mobileNav').onclick = function(){
    var className = '' + navdrop.className + '';
    if ( ~className.indexOf('open-nav') ) {
        this.className = className.replace(' open-nav', '');
    } else {
        this.className += ' open-nav';
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. what do you actually want ? `toggle` class on click on a div ?

Comment: A new class added and removed in the <nav>, when i click on the <div>.

Comment: please check my answer. let me know if this is not something what  you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want. Moreover it's in pure `Javascript`

```js
function classToggle() {
    document.querySelector('#navdrop').classList.toggle('class1');
    document.querySelector('#navdrop').classList.toggle('class2');
}
document.querySelector('#div').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

```css
.class1 {
    border: solid 1px;
}

.class2 {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navdrop" class="class2">
<a href="#">HTML</a> |
<a href="#">CSS</a> |
<a href="#">JavaScript</a> |
<a href="#">jQuery</a>
</nav>
<br/>

<div id="div" >click here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById('navdrop')` instead of just **navdrop**

```js
document.getElementById('mobileNav').onclick = function(){
     var className = '' + document.getElementById('navdrop').className + '';
     if ( className.indexOf('open-nav') > -1 ) {
      document.getElementById('navdrop').className = className.replace('open-nav', ' ');
     } else {
      document.getElementById('navdrop').className += ' open-nav';
     }
    }
```

```css
.open-nav{
  color : red
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
            <nav id="navdrop" class="top-bar">
Nav
</nav>

    <div id="mobileNav" class="mobile-toggle">
    Test
      <i class="icon icon_menu"></i>
    </div>
```

Comment: Usman Rana already fixed my problem but thanks for the reply anyway.